# What is the difference between "STS - Run As - Spring Boot App" vs. using "gradlew bootRun", for running a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, redis

Spring Boot Version: 2.1.5.RELEASE

I have a simple Spring Boot MVC Application that uses Redis for spring session storage.

```
spring:

  session:
    store-type: redis

    redis:
      flush-mode: on-save
      namespace: spring:session

  redis:
    host: localhost
    password: 
    port: 6379
    database: 0
```

When I run it on STS ("Run as" - "Spring Boot App"), it uses my Redis installation for session storage. I can see the keys being added on Redis (keys *).

But, when I run it using bootRun on command prompt, everything related to sessions seems to work fine, but I don't see any keys on the Redis server. It seems like it is not even connecting to my Redis server. I can even safely shutdown Redis without affecting anything.

I have made sure that I have the same system properties between the two modes of run. What could be the difference? Where could it be connecting to in the latter scenario?

[EDIT]

Something I noticed in the log files after enabling TRACE on org.springframework.session -

When run on STS, I see these log entries (expected) -

```
2019-06-27 14:23:47.086 DEBUG No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest. | HP-20111108 | org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.SESSION_LOGGER | nio-8080-exec-1 
2019-06-27 14:23:47.087 DEBUG A new session was created. To help you troubleshoot where the session was created we provided a StackTrace (this is not an error). You can prevent this from appearing by disabling DEBUG logging for org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.SESSION_LOGGER | HP-20111108 | org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.SESSION_LOGGER | nio-8080-exec-1 
java.lang.RuntimeException: For debugging purposes only (not an error)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:332) [spring-session-core-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:354) [spring-session-core-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    .....
2019-06-27 14:24:00.003 DEBUG Cleaning up sessions expiring at Thu Jun 27 14:24:00 CDT 2019 | HP-20111108 | org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisSessionExpirationPolicy | pool-2-thread-1
```

When run using bootRun, this is the only log entry I see -

```
2019-06-27 14:27:05.936  WARN Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [382] milliseconds. | HP-20111108 | org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase | nio-8080-exec-1
```

Could Tomcat be taking over session management when run using bootRun ? How does that happen?

Comment: Do you use the same spring profiles in both cases?

Comment: Yes. I only have one profile

Answer (score 0):

Dang ! Seems this was my fault. My project in STS was off. This is a Gradle project and I had made some changes on the project and didn't know I had to do a "Refresh Gradle Project". Anyway, they are in sync now and behave similarly, but the sad thing is that it is both behaving the wrong way (doesn't use Redis), but I guess that is a separate issue.

Comment: Just so it will help someone - The issue was that I was using a dependency to "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis". Apparently, Spring Boot requires dependency to "org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis" for it to use Spring Session.